# Facebook webhook for pages not working when reply to the message via Facebook Messenger?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-messenger, facebook-webhooks

I am creating a Facebook Webhook for page. It works well when the user sends a message to the page, the result of webhook is returned as an json object:

```
{"entry": [{"changes": [{"field": "conversations", "value": {"thread_id": "t_100015009722515", "page_id": 1863367573935021, "thread_key": "t_100015009722515"}}], "id": "1863367573935021", "time": 1510797239}], "object": "page"}
```

but when logging into the Facebook Messager of the page and reply to user, the webhook does not work?

-webhook-page: `all subscribed`

-permissions: `messages, messaging_postbacks, messaging_optins, message_deliveries, message_reads, messaging_payments, messaging_pre_checkouts, messaging_checkout_updates, messaging_account_linking, messaging_referrals, message_echoes, standby, messaging_handovers, messaging_policy_enforcement, conversations, affiliation, attire, awards, bio, birthday, category, checkins, company_overview, culinary_team, current_location, website, videos, ratings, public_transit, products, product_review, price_range, picture, phone, personal_interests, personal_info, payment_options, parking, name, mission, merchant_review, mention, members, location, live_videos, leadgen, hours, hometown, general_manager, general_info, founded, feed, email, description`

Comment: Please add more details to your question and post sour source code

Comment: How did you make it receive this 'conversations' notification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should listen to [message_echoes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/webhook-events/message-echoes) event in your application to see your messages.

Check out your app event listener.

Comment: Thanks Hya. Let me try